# Customise YouTube controls, title and the whole iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to customise controls, title bar and other things from a YouTube video that I'm creating.
But I cannot find the right parameters that might do so. The ones I'm using are not working basically.

Any thoughts on this?

```
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        controls: 0,
        videoId: 'Sz0UtcKnwb4',
        autoplay: 0,
        frameborder: 0,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        events: {
          'onReady': initialize
        }
      });
    }

function initialize() {
//some action
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) the list of supported parameters in any YouTube embedded player. Example is the `theme` parameter that indicates whether the embedded player will display player controls (like a play button or volume control) within a dark or light control bar.

Another example is the `controls` parameter that indicates whether the video player controls are displayed. For IFrame embeds that load a Flash player, it also defines when the controls display in the player as well as when the player will load.

Supported values are:

- **controls=0** – Player controls do not display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the Flash player loads immediately.
- **controls=1** (default) – Player controls display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the controls display immediately and the Flash player also loads immediately.
- **controls=2** – Player controls display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the controls display and the Flash player loads after the user initiates the video playback.

You can also check on these tutorials:

- [YouTube Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)
- [Making a Custom YouTube Video Player With YouTube's APIs](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/)
- [How to Customize YouTube Embeddable Player Features](http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-embed-hacks/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: According to the doc, the theme parameter has been deprecated for the HTML5 player. HTML5 players now always use the dark theme since August 19, 2015